# How can I change the user profile Icon using Glide in mikepenz navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-glide

I have already checked the documentation:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer
 and I understand that mikepenz nav drawer doesn't have an image loader so I should use this :
  //initialize and create the image loader logic

```
DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
    @Override
    public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder, String tag) {
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
        Glide.clear(imageView);
    }
```

but I can't seem to know how to call it or use it, I wanna be able to use it here:

```
  AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(activity)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.clouds_background)
                .addProfiles(
                        new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(name).withEmail(email)
                        .withIcon()
                        .withTextColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                )
```

It should be used within withIcon()

Comment: which library you are using for navigation drawer?

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer @HiteshSarsava

Comment: where are you initializing  `DrawerImageLoader`

Answer (score 1):

see the below to add url image:

```
 new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon("https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1476232?v=3&s=460").withIdentifier(100);
```

check the this document [link1](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/DrawerActivity.java) and [link2](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CustomApplication.java#L42)

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder and call like this:
Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);

Insert this into your "DrawerImageLoader initialization":

```
  @Override
            public Drawable placeholder(Context ctx, String tag) {
                //define different placeholders for different imageView targets
                //default tags are accessible via the DrawerImageLoader.Tags
                //custom ones can be checked via string. see the CustomUrlBasePrimaryDrawerItem LINE 111
                if (DrawerImageLoader.Tags.PROFILE.name().equals(tag)) {
                    return DrawerUIUtils.getPlaceHolder(ctx);
                } else if (DrawerImageLoader.Tags.ACCOUNT_HEADER.name().equals(tag)) {
                    return new IconicsDrawable(ctx).iconText(" ").backgroundColorRes(com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.R.color.primary).sizeDp(56);
                } else if ("customUrlItem".equals(tag)) {
                    return new IconicsDrawable(ctx).iconText(" ").backgroundColorRes(R.color.md_red_500).sizeDp(56);
                }


                return super.placeholder(ctx, tag);
            }
        });
```

Comment: and then how can I be able to place the image loaded as a profile icon in my navigation drawer ?